# Shift/reduce conflict with infix sections

Tags: yacc, infix-notation, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict, ocamlyacc

I'm having trouble with a yacc-like implementation (using ocamlyacc, in particular) of a grammar that includes ordinary infix operations plus infix sections, like in Haskell. I desire all of these to be grammatical:

```
(+1)
(1+)
(+)
(1+1)
```

However, I haven't been able to get this working, even by fiddling with associativity/precedence declarations. I can see in the grammar.output where the problem is happening (it's shifting where I want it to reduce), but I haven't been able to coax it to go the way I want. Here is a simplified demonstration of the problem.

lex.mll has:

```
{
  open Parse
  exception Eof
}
rule token = parse
  | [' ' '\t'] { token lexbuf }
  | ['\n'] { EOL }
  | ['0'-'9']+ as num {INT(int_of_string num)}
  | '+' { PLUS }
  | '*' { TIMES }
  | '(' { LPAREN }
  | ')' { RPAREN }
  | eof { raise Eof }
```

main.ml has:

```
let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    while true do
      let result = Parse.start Lex.token lexbuf in
      print_string result; print_newline(); flush stdout
    done
  with Lex.Eof -> exit 0
```

and parse.mly (where the trouble lies) has:

```
%token <int> INT
%token PLUS TIMES
%token LPAREN RPAREN
%token EOL

%left PLUS
%left TIMES

%start start
%type <string> start
%%

start:
| expr EOL {$1}
;

expr:
| application {$1}
| expr PLUS expr {"[" ^ $1 ^ "+" ^ $3 ^"]"}
| expr TIMES expr {"[" ^ $1 ^ "*" ^ $3 ^"]"}
;

section:
| LPAREN atom PLUS RPAREN { "(" ^ $2 ^ " +)" }
| LPAREN PLUS atom RPAREN { "(+ " ^ $3 ^ ")" }
| LPAREN PLUS RPAREN { "(+)" }
;

application:
| atom {$1}
| application atom {"[" ^ $1 ^ " " ^ $2 ^ "]"}
;

atom:
| INT {string_of_int $1}
| section { $1 }
| LPAREN expr RPAREN { "(" ^ $2 ^ ")" }
;

%%
```

Running `ocamlyacc` on that tells me there is `1 shift/reduce conflict`. In particular here is the relevant part of the verbose log:

```
Rules:
   6  section : LPAREN atom PLUS RPAREN
   ...
   9  application : atom
...
12: shift/reduce conflict (shift 21, reduce 9) on PLUS
state 12
        section : LPAREN atom . PLUS RPAREN  (6)
        application : atom .  (9)

        PLUS  shift 21
        INT  reduce 9
        MINUS  reduce 9
        TIMES  reduce 9
        LPAREN  reduce 9
        RPAREN  reduce 9
...
state 21
        section : LPAREN atom PLUS . RPAREN  (6)

        RPAREN  shift 26
        .  error
```

And running the compiled program will correctly parse all of the following:

```
(1+)
(+1)
(+)
1+2
```

but fails with:

```
(1+2)
```

If on the other hand, I create a dummy token `HIGH` with high precedence:

```
%left PLUS MINUS
%left TIMES
%nonassoc HIGH
```

and then put `%prec HIGH` on the Rule 9:

```
application: atom %prec HIGH {$1}
```

in that case `(1+2)` will parse but `(1+)` won't.

I understand the general background of shift/reduce conflicts. I just can't figure out how to negotiate it to solve this parsing challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out a lot of your grammar, you have the following productions, all of which could be simultaneously feasible.

```
atom:    LPAREN expr RPAREN
expr:           expr PLUS expr
section: LPAREN atom PLUS RPAREN
```

So let's say we've just read <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> -- that is, an `LPAREN` and an `INT` -- and the next token up is <kbd>+</kbd>. At this point, we need to reduce the `INT` to an `atom`, but we can't tell whether what follows will match the `atom` or the `section` rule. To match the `atom` rule, we'd need to reduce the `atom` to an `expr` -- by way of `application` -- but to match the `section` rule, we need it to stay as an `atom`. So we have a shift/reduce conflict; we don't know whether we need to shift the <kbd>+</kbd> now, or after doing some more unit reductions.

The simple solution is to delay the decision. If the `section` rule were:

```
section: LPAREN expr PLUS RPAREN
```

then there wouldn't be a problem. We'd continue the unit reductions until we got an `expr`, then we'd shift the <kbd>+</kbd>, and then we'd either see an <kbd>)</kbd> or we'd see something which could start an `expr`. Conflict resolved.

Of course, that changes the language, making it more permissive. We might not want to accept:

```
( 3 + 4 + )
```

or

```
( (+) 3 4 + )
```

But the resulting grammar is not ambiguous. We could just let the parser continue and then issue an error message when reducing `section`, by checking to see whether `$2` was appropriately restricted. (This is a pretty common technique, and there is nothing wrong with it.)

Alternatively, we could separate the

```
expr: expr PLUS expr
```

rule into two mutually-exclusive alternatives:

```
expr: atom PLUS expr
expr: expr_not_an_atom PLUS expr
```

This would also solve the conflict, because the `atom` could not be reduced to `expr_not_an_atom`. But it leaves open the question of how to define `expr_not_an_atom`.

As it happens, I'm pretty sure that is possible but it's not quite trivial, and the consequences will ripple down the grammar. I can't give you an algorithm, either, because CFGs -- unlike regular expressions -- are not closed under negation or set difference. But basically, you need to just cascade through the non-terminals, splitting them so each alternative will fit either into `atom` or `expr_not_an_atom`- This is also a legitimate approach, but the resulting grammar can be hard to read.

If you were using `bison`, you would have another alternative: generate a GLR grammar. As long as your language is not ambiguous, the GLR grammar will find the correct parse, possibly slightly more slowly but with a lot less effort on your part.

In case it helps, [here's a slightly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450769/1566221) in which I produced a fully-worked out solution to splitting non-terminals.

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind having `(1+2+)` or even `(1*2+)` but `(1+2*)` and `(*1+2)` should fail (as they do in Haskell). The way I accomplished this, with your guidance, was to have the expression rule return a pair of the former payload plus an `int` marking the precedence of its head operator. Then the section rules could verify that the marker is <= the precedence of the leading/trailing operator that constitutes the section. And as far as I can see, this is working perfectly for this toy grammar.