# How bison parses x = (int)+b

Tags: bison, yacc

I am confused how bison will parse / resolve the conflict in this expression assuming "int" is a type and the first expression is typecasting and the second one is just a plain addition or if "a" is a type alias it is same as first. Assuming that language allows for giving alias names to a existing type.

```
x = (int)+b => typecast to "int" the "+b"
x = (a)+b => addition expression / typecast to "a" the "+b"
```

Bison has to know if the identifier in the bracket is a type or variable to be able to resolve it. How does it handle that ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448189/bison-reduce-reduce-conflict-with-casting-and-expression-parentheses

Comment: Yes ! Sharing of symbol table might work. Flex can output the token identifier or type name once it can read the symbol table.